# Getting a method parameters in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

How to print the parameters of a specific method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters don't have types so you can't print those.  It seems that you want to print the method header which provides the name of the method and the names of the parameters.  You already have the name of the method so you need to get the names of the parameters.  The only way to get the names of the parameters is from the original source string.  Here's a nice way to extract the parameter names from the source string.  In this example, I'm getting the name of the parameter of the printOn: method in class Object.

```
(Parser new parse: (Object sourceCodeAt: #printOn:) class: Object) arguments
  collect: [:each | each name]
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example for a method with more than one parameter?

Comment: (Parser new parse: (Magnitude sourceCodeAt: #between:and:) class: Magnitude) arguments
  collect: [:each | each name]

Comment: I need to call sourceCodeAt for a method. But I have this method in a variable as String. Instead of X I have 'X'. How can I change it to X ,as a method instance, to be able to call sourceCodeAt on it?

Comment: (Parser new parse: aString class: Object) arguments
  collect: [:each | each name]

Answer (score 1):

In Pharo3 it is even easier:

```
(Object>>#printOn:) argumentNames
```